# How to configure writing to multiple Appenders in log4j2?

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j

Prior to log4j2

```
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ELASTIC=com.my.ElasticSearchAppender
log4j.rootLogger=FILE,ELASTIC # Works
```

log4j2

```
appender.elastic.type=Elasticsearch
appender.elastic.name=elastic
appender.rolling.type=RollingFile
appender.rolling.name=rolling
rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref=rolling,elastic # does not work
rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref=rolling # works
rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref=elastic # works
```

I get the below error.

```
Log4J Updater ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling,elastic" for logger config "root"
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remark**: your Log4j 1.x configuration is incorrect, since the configuration of the root logger **must** start with a level followed by zero or more appender names, e.g.:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, FILE, ELASTIC
```

Since version 2.17.2 (cf. [LOG4J2-3341](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3341)) the same shorthand notation is available in the Log4j2 properties format:

```
rootLogger=INFO, file, elastic
```

The full notation can be easily converted from the simpler XML format:

```xml
<Root level="INFO">
    <AppenderRef ref="file"/>
    <AppenderRef ref="elastic"/>
</Root>
```

Each `<AppenderRef>` element results in a `appenderRef.<unique identifier>` property:

```
rootLogger.level = INFO
rootLogger.appenderRef.<0>.ref = file
rootLogger.appenderRef.<1>.ref = elastic
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue

```
rootLogger.appenderRefs=rolling,elastic
rootLogger.appenderRef.elastic.ref=elastic
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref=rolling
```

Comment: @pkarwasz @piotr-p-karwasz

I dont need `rootLogger.appenderRefs=rolling,elastic` and just `rootLogger.appenderRef.elastic.ref=elastic` `rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref=rolling` will do? I will test it anyway but just wanted to ask.

Comment: `rootLogger.appenderRefs` does not exist. Other similar properties like `loggers` still exist for backward compatibility, but are not necessary.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz May I know what does `rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref = rolling` do?  As per my understanding it is setting root appender to rolling only. `rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref = rolling` property is currently set in the product and customer already have this property. I am adding `rootLogger.appenderRef.elastic.ref=elastic`
`rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref=rolling` as you suggested and want to remove  `rootLogger.appenderRef.root.ref = rolling`. Just wanted to confirm if there will be any side effects.